# Is there a professional name for these graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

A graph is called **regular graph** if degree of each vertex is equal. A regular graph with vertices of degree $k$ is called a $k$‑regular graph.

If any vertex degree of a graph is either $k$ or $l$, does such a graph have a professional name?

I want to name it “**semiregular graph**”. But the name already seems to mean something. For example:

> A semiregular graph is a bipartite graph which, from the point of
> view of the vertices of one of the partite sets, appears to be
> distance regular.

- David L Powers (1988) Semiregular graphs and their algebra, Linear and Multilinear Algebra, 24:1, 27-37, DOI: 10.1080/03081088808817894

Or we can see in [a_study_of_semiregular_graphs](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/axel/papers/northup:a_study_of_semiregular_graphs.pdf):

A graph is *semiregular* if each vertex in the graph is distance $2$ away from exactly the same number of vertices. If each vertex is distance $2$ from $n$ other vertices, we call that graph $n$-semiregular.  The figure below  shows some examples of semiregular graphs.

[image: fig1]

Comment: There's a more specific notion of "biregular" graph, which has your property but is additionally bipartite such that the partitions are precisely "the vertices with the same degree".

Comment: Thank you.  I also saw "biregular"  by querying the wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph.  The "bipartite" is not necessary in my case.

Comment: There are always hemi and demi if nobody has a more insightful suggestion

Comment: Or, going in the opposite direction, 2-regular, or 2-quasi-regular

Comment: Or, more specifically, you may simply call it a $\{k,l\}$-regular graph.